# opensource implementation of encrypted qr codes

Tags: c#, open-source, cryptography, barcode-scanner, qr-code

Can you point me to an opensource implementation of an encrypted qr code similar to what quickmark is doing? check this out:

http://www.quickmark.com.tw/En/diy/?qrEncrypt

If possible, an implementation that works on both mobile and pc applications.

Here is a quick explanation on how QuickMark works http://uvsar.blogspot.com/2009/05/secure-qr-and-qm-codes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They appear to be simply encoding the encrypted data as a URL with the prefix 'pe:', followed by the raw encrypted data. There isn't a standard for this, so you can do it however you want, really. Are you trying to make something compatible with their system? If not, what are your requirements? I'm finding it hard to understand why you'd want an encrypted QR code.

Comment: the QuickMark encrypted code when read using the kaywa reader or other qr scanner will output garbage if you try. but with QuickMark scanner it will prompt for a password. I will use encrypted QR codes to store private messages on a QR code that will prompt for a password. Here is a quick explanation http://uvsar.blogspot.com/2009/05/secure-qr-and-qm-codes.html

Comment: @Aivan In contrast to that post, the QR standard doesn't directly support encryption - QuickMark are just layering it on top. The question still comes back to whether or not you want to read/write codes in the same format as QuickMark, in which case you need to find out how they're formatting them and what cipher they're using. None of the use-cases in that doc seem compelling, though - if you want to authenticate things, you should use an HMAC, and in the case of ticketing you probably just want to embed a unique code that you can look up in a DB.

Answer (score 0):

It seems simpler to create a password-protected web page and just encode its URL. Then it works on any reader (though you have to host a webpage somewhere.)

Comment: That's not the point of this, QR's are made to bring the offline world to the online world. Hence, the QR code could be in a paper or in a wall

Comment: Of course -- what's that to do with what the QR code contains? If you mean you want a completely off-line solution, no there is no standard for this.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://twit88.com/platform/projects/show/mt-qrcode) C# Open Source QR code library can be usefull. It, works for mobile applications too.